# redux pre-binding through bindActionCreators, an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Throughout my redux App, I frequently finding myself using the following pattern

```
// declare an action creator in a centralized / state management related location in the App (i.e. not the components/containers)
const myActionCreator1 = () => (dispatch) => { ... }
const myActionCreator2 = createAction(ACTION_2)
// then later in a mapDispatchToProps of a Container component
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  bindActionCreators({myActionCreator1, myActionCreator2}, dispatch);
}
```

Is these cases, is it an anti-pattern to **pre-bind** the action creators? given that there is only 1 dispatcher in redux working against 1 store?

i.e.

```
// actionCreators.ts
export const myActionCreators = {
  myActionCreator: bindActionCreators(..., dispatch)
}
```

If this is pattern has no downside that would be good news for conciseness ....

Clarification

the conciseness benefit will only be apparent when multiple components re-use the same action creator. As these components will no longer require a **mapDispatchToProps** for straight-forward cases like the examples above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connect` function supports an "object shorthand" syntax for the second argument.  Instead of creating a `mapDispatchToProps` function that receives `dispatch` (and probably uses `bindActionCreators` inside), you can just pass an object full of action creators directly to `connect`:

```
const actionCreators = {
    addTodo,
    toggleTodo
};

export default connect(null, actionCreators)(MyComponent);
```

That object full of action creators will be automatically run through `bindActionCreators`, and calling `this.props.addTodo("Buy Milk")` will dispatch the action creator appropriately.

I discussed some of the advantages of this approach in my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: Why use action creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/).

Comment: thanks! I didn't know that redux feature, definitely saves key strokes in the canonical cases